# Прайс-калькулятор каждой строки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица, очень большая, с прайсом услуг.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<thead>
   <th>Предмет</th>
   <th>В наличии</th>
   <th>Цена</th>
   <th>Кол-во</th>
   <th>Общая цена</th>
 </thead>
<tr>
 <td>ручка гелевая</td>
 <td>40шт</td>
 <td id="cena">5</td>
 <td><input id="colvo" onkeyup="summ()"></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ручка шариковая</td>
<td>40шт</td>
<td id="cena">10</td>
<td><input id="colvo" onkeyup="summ()"></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Как можно подсчитывать суммы отдельных строк, не объявляя при этом для каждой из них свою переменную? Еще раз повторюсь: ОЧЕНЬ большая таблица.

Comment: @ReeQx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так ( http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/Lazu596w/1/ ):

Задать ячейке с суммой контрольный класс и дата атрибут с суммой, примерно так:

```
<td class="js-summ" data-summ="100">100 рублей</td>
```

Сделать массив нужных ему строк и посчитать их:

```
var rows = [1,2,7,9];
var $rows = $('table').find('tr');
var result = 0;

$.each(rows,function(i,e){
    var $target = $rows.eq(e).find('.js-summ');
    var thisResult = parseFloat($target.attr('data-summ'));
    if (typeof(thisResult) === 'number') { result += thisResult; }
});

console.log(result); // result here
```

P.S. Не забываем, что строчки считаются от нуля. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Переделать таблицу. Id на странице должен быть уникальным. Он же Вам вообще не нужен, замените его на name. Оберните каждую строчку следующим образом `<form>код строчки</form>`

```
<form>
Доступно <output name='dostupno'>40</output><br>
Цена <output name='cena'>10</output><br>
Количество <input name='colvo' type='number' oninput='colvo.value = Math.min(colvo.value, dostupno.value);result.value = cena.value * colvo.value'><br>
Сумма <output name='result'>0</output><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `onkeyup="summ()"` на `onkeyup="summ(this)"`. 
И добавить скрипт:

```
<SCRIPT>
function summ(o){
r=o.parentElement.parentElement;
r.cells(4).children(0).innerHTML=parseInt(r.cells(2).innerHTML)*(o.value==""?0:parseInt(o.value))
}
</SCRIPT>
```